# Laravel shop with different products

Tags: database, laravel, database-design, relationship, laravel-8

I have this platform (that uses Backpack for the Admin Cruds) in which I want to have various types of products (shoes, sweatshirts, pants, shirts...).
I'm encountering a bit of problems coming out with an efficient and simple way to organize the app structure. I want to avoid having all the necessary fields for the various products in one big table using just the ones related to the particular product I'm storing, and also having different tables that repeat the attributes that are in common between the product types (e.g. owner_id, product_model_id...).
What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

if you ask about e commerce structure , you should look at open source scripts firstly like magento , opencart , bagisto , etc.
you should know how to represent the product with different attribute ( EAV concept ) like product have color and another dont have . you should know feature of the product like dimensions , weight , height and another feature .
you should know about manufactures and taxes related with the product . so i advice you to look at any opensource project database . ( i think opencart database enough to design medium e commerce project ).